# General solution of $6ty'+y = t^2$ using an integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution, $y(t)$, which solves the problem below, by the method of integrating factors.

I need help solving this problem:

$6t \frac{dy}{dt} +y = t^2$

I know it has to be broken up into $p(x)$ and $q(x)$

without $\frac{dy}{dx}$

$$6ty'+y=t^2$$

$$y'+y/6t=1/6t$$

So $p(x) = \frac{y}{6t}$, which when integrated gives $\int p(x) \;dx= -\frac{1}{6} \ln t$, and
$q(x) = \frac{1}{6t}$.

I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: you have any idea how to get started? have you tried an example problem in class?

Answer (score 1):

$$ 6t \,\dfrac{dy}{dt} +y =t^2 \; \color{orange}{(\div 6t)}
\\ \dfrac{dy}{dt} + \dfrac{1}{6t}\,y = \dfrac{t}{6} $$

Integrating factor: $u(t)=e^{\int{\dfrac{1}{6t}\,dt}}=e^{\dfrac{1}{6}\ln{t}}\Rightarrow u(t)=t^{\dfrac{1}{6}}$

$$ \color{purple}{t^{\dfrac{1}{6}}}\dfrac{dy}{dt} + \dfrac{ \color{purple}{t^{\dfrac{1}{6}}}}{6t}\,y = \color{purple}{t^{\dfrac{1}{6}}} \dfrac{t}{6}
\\ t^{\dfrac{1}{6}}\dfrac{dy}{dt} + \dfrac{1}{6t^{\dfrac{5}{6}}}\,y = \dfrac{t^{\dfrac{7}{6}}}{6} $$

$$ \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(t^{\dfrac{1}{6}}y\right)=\dfrac{t^{\dfrac{7}{6}}}{6}
\\ \int{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(t^{\dfrac{1}{6}}y\right)\,dt}
=\int{\dfrac{t^{\dfrac{7}{6}}}{6}\,dx}
\\ t^{\dfrac{1}{6}}y =\dfrac{1}{6} \left(\dfrac{6}{13}t^{\dfrac{13}{6}}\right)+c
\\ \color{blue}{y(t)=\dfrac{1}{13}t^2+c\,t^{-\dfrac{1}{6}}} $$

Comment: You're welcome (y).